# What is the point of the (?:x) character?

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Non capturing group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group)

I'm learning regex in JavaScript, and the `(?:x)` character or "non-capturing parentheses" just doesn't make sense to me. If you don't want the match to be remembered why not just abandon parentheses altogether? What's the advantage of using `/(?:x)/` instead of just `/x/`?

Comment: I believe I saw that one while researching, but the example seemed complex. Since I'm learning I need simple answers. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because you might need the parentheses for other reasons. For example, suppose you want to capture the digit at the end of `abababababab9`. If you wrote `ab*(\d)` then it would match `abbbbbbbbb9`. You need to parenthesize the `ab` so that the `*` operator will repeat the whole thing. `(ab)*(\d)`. But maybe you don't care about how many times `ab` was repeated. That's where you use `(?:)`: `(?:ab)*(\d)`.

Answer (score 3):

You need it to define sub-patterns to be used in alternative matches or with quantifiers, that would apply to entire sub-pattern without wasting capture slot. For example, you can use `(?:)` together with `|` to provide alternate matches in middle of regexp without capturing it.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following cases:

`(?:aa|bb|cc)`

`(?:abc)?`

You can use the non-capturing group to match patterns that have more complex sub-patterns. In certain cases using the non-capturing group syntax will result in a more efficient regular expression as well.

Answer (score 1):

> If you don't want the match to be remembered why not just abandon parentheses altogether? What's the advantage of using /(?:x)/ instead of just /x/?

It used when you want to **group** chars, but you don't want to **remember** them. If you remove the parentheses, you can't group a sequence of characters. So, for instance:

```
/foo|bar/.test("foo") // true
/foo|bar/.test("bar") // true
```

If you want to achieve a pattern that match `foor` and `fbar` you have to group the characters in the middle:

```
/f(?:oo|ba)r/.test("fbar") // true
/f(?:oo|ba)r/.test("foor") // true
```

Of course you can also group and remember the group, but if instead `test` your using `match` or other methods where the array returned is significant to you, then you have to use `(?:` instead.